# Will searchlogic work with Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

If not what are my alternatives?

Comment: I actually decided to use both Thinking Sphinx and Metawhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Metawhere - http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/
looks like a promising alternative. 
ps: discovered metawhere through rubyflow.com.
MetaSearch (http://metautonomo.us/2010/03/07/metasearch-object-based-searching-for-rails-3/)
by the same author is actually closer to Searchlogic.

Answer (score 3):

Please use Railsdog's rd_searchlogic (3.0.0.rc4), it's modified to be fully compatible with Rails3. You can extract this plugin from Spree 0.30 project.

Comment: I confirm, it doesn't work: NameError: undefined local variable or method `assert_valid_keys' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000104f2c740>

Answer (score 2):

scoped-search - https://github.com/wvanbergen/scoped_search

Answer (score 1):

Searchlogic performs 2 functions; it provides both an extension to scopes, and a form object.

The most current, best (IMO) scope extension (successor to MetaWhere):

http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/

Most current & best search form object (successor to MetaSearch):

https://github.com/ernie/ransack

EDIT:

I'm currently assessing how well these integrate. I did enjoy having them together in Searchlogic.