# Rails - Searchlogic to search condition as an array of value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, searchlogic

I have two models **Employee** & **Unit**. **Unit** has many **Employees**. I am using SearchLogic to search employee model. What is the equivalent of below SQL in Searchlogic

```
employees.unit_id IN (1,2,3)
```

I have tried both

```
unit_id_equals_all[] 
unit_id_equals_any[]
```

But nothing works. Can anyone help?

Thanks, Abhilash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Employee.unit_id_equals([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. I get this error "wrong number of bind variables (2 for 1) in: employees.unit_id IN (?)"

Comment: Could you give more hints about the error message? such as when is the message being generated? I can't get why there were 2 variables......

Comment: In my search view I selected 2 units and passed it as an array, if I select 5 it will say 5 for 1. My params hash is like this --> unit_id_equals"=>["332", "333"]

Comment: BTW, Employee.unit_id_equals([332,333]) works fine in the console

Comment: Yes this should work. Are you sure you are `...equals(["332", "333])` instead of `...equals("332", "333")`? The latter one give the same error message while the former one is correct and worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This is my view code <%= check_box_tag "search[unit_id_equals][]", unit.id %> Is there something wrong here?

Comment: Found the reason. This is an issue in searchlogic Employee.unit_id_equals([1, 2, 3]) works but Employee.search(:unit_id_equals => [1, 2, 3]).all does not work http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/issues/issue/64

Comment: @Angela, ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655818/will-searchlogic-work-with-rails-3 most likely searchlogic is not working in rails 3 but you could simply switch to metawhere and this solution should work too.

Comment: @Peterwong do I need to isolate just the id's?  Or can I pass an array of user objects (for example, I am using the acts_as_network gem with User.friends creating the array.

Comment: Since I have a long time not using search gems, I do not sure if it is ok. If your `.friends` not a so long list, `User.friends.collect(&:id)` would not slow at all ;D

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here.

I have no idea why this worked for me, or why I even tried it, since it is undocumented. But I changed the _equals to _in, and it produced the SQL with IN, and worked perfectly.

```
Employee.unit_id_in([1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

We had this same issue with a Rails 2.3.12 project.  With searchlogic 2.4.7 we could do:

```
User.id_equals([1,2,3])
```

After upgrading to search logic 2.5.8 (deprecation messages in the old one were cluttering out cucumber and spec output), this syntax no longer worked.  It threw this error just like the one above:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (users.id = 1, 2, 3)
```

After trying the solutions above, we found that these two syntax alternatives worked:

```
User.id_in([1,2,3]) <-- as suggested above
User.id_equals_any([1,2,3])
```

In other words, without the "_any" the new search logic produces invalid mysql.  Looking into when and why this change might have occurred, I found this commit discussion:

[Github commit changing handling of arrays](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic/commit/6ce976f313ead346cac46d877ea4afba39f01848#comments)

The upshot of this change and the discussion was to require _any for times when you want a match against any value in the array, and otherwise just pass the array in to the equals statement directly without changing the SQL to "IN" as needed for multiple values.

Reverting to 2.4.7 clears the error.  Changing all the calls to the more explicit _any or _in is what we ended up doing in order to avoid deprecation errors.  Hope this helps and adds to the very helpful answers above.